# Summing up values of checkboxes, with -minimum selected condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with X number of groups of checkboxes with price values. 
I have assigned one condition to each group.

Lets assume that we have 2 groups:

1st group condition: sum all the values together, except the first 3 selected 
(NOT the first 3 in the index but first 3 selected and every selection after that)

2nd group condition: sum all the values together, except the first 2 selected 
(NOT the first 2 in the index but first 2 selected and every selection after that)

```
var minLimit1 = 3;
var minLimit2 = 2;

$(":input", "#myForm").each(function(){

    if(this.type == 'checkbox'){



    }

});
```

How can I implement that using jQuery or plain js?

EDIT: SAMPLE FORM CODE

```
<form id="myForm">
 <fieldset class="required">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1.30" name="group1" id="id-1">
  <label for="id-1"><span>Component 1</span><em>(€1.30)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1.00" name="group1" id="id-2">
  <label for="id-2"><span>Component 2</span><em>(€1.00)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="0.50" name="group1" id="id-3">
  <label for="id-3"><span>Component 3</span><em>(€0.50)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="0.25" name="group1" id="id-4">
  <label for="id-4"><span>Component 4</span><em>(€0.25)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1.75" name="group1" id="id-5">
  <label for="id-5"><span>Component 5</span><em>(€1.75)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="2.00" name="group1" id="id-6">
  <label for="id-6"><span>Component 6</span><em>(€2.00)</em></label>
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset class="required">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1.20" name="group2" id="id-7">
  <label for="id-7"><span>Component 1</span><em>(€1.20)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1.10" name="group2" id="id-8">
  <label for="id-8"><span>Component 2</span><em>(€1.10)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="0.40" name="group2" id="id-9">
  <label for="id-9"><span>Component 3</span><em>(€0.40)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="0.35" name="group2" id="id-10">
  <label for="id-10"><span>Component 4</span><em>(€0.35)</em></label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1.15" name="group2" id="id-11">
  <label for="id-11"><span>Component 5</span><em>(€1.15)</em></label>

 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note: I want the latest clicked and further to be added in the summary, not the last in the index.

Comment: provide some html in order to see how you group checkboxes and better explanation of excluded elements

Comment: JSFIDDLE.net is a place to show your code too

Comment: My html is dynamically created. It can have 1 to x number of grouped checkboxes. And some of those could have conditions like the ones explained above.
I am using the .each method to read all the elements in a form and decide which to sum and which not based on user selections.

Comment: @mallix  regardless of how html is created it has a structure to it and samples can easily be pulled from source of live page. You have to help us help you. SHow your code also

Comment: @charlietfl I ve added my form code. I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution does what you need. Demo adds class to the labels of values being calculated to make it easier to determin that concept is correct

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MTJtF/2

```
/* can store values in array, or as data attribute of html */

var min_limits = [3, 2];

$('#myForm .required input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('fieldset.required')
    var parentIdx = $('fieldset.required').index($group);
    /* can store values in array, or as data attribute of html */
    var minLimit = $group.data('min_limit') || min_limits[parentIdx];
    var $selected = $group.find(':checked').slice(minLimit);
   $group.find('.counted').removeClass('counted')
    var sum = 0;
    if ($selected.length) {
        $selected.each(function() {
            sum +=1*$(this).val();
            $(this).next().addClass('counted')
        })

    } else {
        sum = 'Limit not met';
    }

    $group.find('.sum').text('Sum= '+sum)

})
```

​

Comment: your solution works the same us Kelvin s. It is adding the last value according to the index, not the latest clicked.
If I check from the 2nd Group, Component 1 then 3 then 2, it sums the value of the last checkbox in the index, which is Component 3.
Same results for the 1st Group of Checkboxes

Comment: OK.. your explanation was not at all clear ( see request for better explanation)  Try this version:  http://jsfiddle.net/MTJtF/3/ Code can probably be refactored a bit to lighten it up, but when changing from one version to another is not worth streamlining until sure it works

Comment: it works like a charm!! I am sorry for not being 100% clear right from the start. I am not sure though how this could be used inside my .each implementation.

Comment: I am scanning the whole form right from start each time a checkbox is clicked. Your solution is very helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter passed to `$.each()` is `index`, which will be helpful here.

In this code, we assume your checkboxes are grouped by `fieldset` elements with classes `"group1"`, `"group2"`, etc.

```
var conditions = {
        group1: 3,
        group2: 2
    },
    total = 0,
    key, condition;

// Loop through all the conditions
for (key in conditions) {
    condition = conditions[key];
    // Loop through all the checked checkboxes in fieldset.group1, fieldset.group2, etc
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', '#myForm fieldset.' + key).each(function(inputIndex) {
        // Check if the current checkbox's index is higher than the minimum
        if ((inputIndex + 1) > condition) {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QfSxw/2/

Edit: Simplified the code considerably

Comment: I want the latest clicked to be added not the last in the index

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I properly understand the format of these checkboxes, but I am assuming that you can tell the difference between group 1 checkboxes and group 2 checkboxes.  If so, I would suggest keeping track of the number of checkboxes that have been marked so far to know when to start summing up the values.  For example:

```
// The minimum number that must be checked
var minLimit1 = 3;
var minLimit2 = 2;
// The number checked per group
var numGroup1 = 0;
var numGroup2 = 0;
//The sum of the checkboxes over the group's minLimit that are checked
var sumGroup1 = 0;
var sumGroup2 = 0;

$(":input", "#myForm").each(function () {
    if ((this.type == 'checkbox') && (this.checked == true)) {
        // This code is just for Group 1 right now. Depending on how you differentiate
        // between each group, you could either have a check in here for each group
        // (or some kind of loop if the number of groups is variable), or have a separate
        // each statement for each group.

        if (numGroup1 >= minLimit1) {
            // If the minLimit has already been reached, then increment the sum
            sumGroup1++;
        }

        numGroup1++;
    }
});
```